Why automorphism group of a Hermitian symmetric domain has trivial center?
Definition: A Hermitian symmetric domain is a Hermitian manifold that is connected, homogeneous, has a symmetry at some point (by homogenity hence every point), and has negative curvature.
I want to prove for such a domain $M$ the biholomorphism group $G=\operatorname{Hol}(M)$ has trivial center.
It seems that we should use the symmetries. Say, let $a\in Z(G)$, then for any point $p\in M$ and its symmetry $s_p$, we have $a(p)=as_p(p)=s_pa(p)$, thus $a(p)$ is a fixed point of $s_p$ but then I don't how to proceed.

This is probably not the most direct argument...
Theorem 4.6 of Chapter VIII of Helgason Differential Geometry, Lie Groups, and Symmetric Spaces states that a hermitian symmetric domain is simply-connected, hence cannot have any non-trivial covering spaces.
Now suppose $a\in Z(G)$ is not the identity. Then I claim for any $p\in M$ we have $a(p)\ne p$. Indeed, suppose otherwise, that $a(p)=p$ for some $p\in M$. Then since $G$ is transitive for any $q\in M$ there is some $g\in G$ such that $g(p)=q$. Now
$$a(q)=a(g(p))=g(a(p))=g(p)=q,$$
so $a$ fixes all points.
Thus, $\langle a\rangle\subset Z(G)$ acts freely on $M$ and so $M/(p\sim a(p))$ is a hermitian symmetric domain. But it admits $M$ as a connected covering space, which is a contradiction.
